# How to structure object: OOP, composition

Tags: oop, inheritance, composition

I have an object, let's call it a Request, that has associations to several other objects like:

```
Employee submitter;
Employee subjectsManager;
Employee pointOfContact;
```

And several value properties like strings, dates, and enums.

Now, I also need to keep track of another object, the subject, but this can be one of 3 different types of people.  For simplicity let's just talk about 2 types: Employee and Consultant.  Their data comes from different repositories and they have different sets of fields, some overlapping.  So say an employee has a

```
String employeeName;
String employeeId;
String socialSecurityNumber;
```

Whereas a consultant has

```
String consultantName;
String socialSecurityNumber;
String phoneNumber;
```

One terrible idea is that the Request has both a Consultant and an Employee, and setSubject(Consultant) assigns one, setSubject(Employee) assigns the other.  This sounds awful.  One of my primary goals is to avoid "if the subject is this type then do this..." logic.

My thought is that perhaps an EmployeeRequest and a ConsultantRequest should extend Request, but I'm not sure how, say, setSubject would work.  I would want it to be an abstract method in the base class but I don't know what the signature would be since I don't know what type the parameter would be.

So then it makes sense to go at it from an interface perspective.  One important interface is that these Request objects will be passed to a single webservice that I don't own.  I will have to map the object's fields in a somewhat complex manner that partially makes sense.  For fields like name and SSN the mapping is straightforward, but many of the fields that don't line up across all types of people are dumped into a concatenated string AdditionalInfo field (wump wump).  So they'll all have a getAdditionalInfo method, a getName, etc, and if there's any fields that don't line up they can do something special with that one.

So that makes me feel like the Request itself should not necessarily be subclassed but could contain a reference to an ISubjectable (or whatever) that implements the interface needed to get the values to send across the webservice.  This sounds pretty decent and prevents a lot of "if the subject is an employee then do this..."

However, I would still at times need to access the additional fields that only a certain type of subject has, for example on a display or edit page, so that brings me right back to "if subject is instance of an employee then go to the edit employee page..."  This may be unavoidable though and if so I'm ok with that.

Just for completeness I'll mention the "union of all possible fields" approach -- don't think I'd care to do that one either.

Is the interface approach the most sensible or am I going about it wrong?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A generic solution comes to mind; that is, if the language you're using supports it:

```
class Request<T extends Subject> {
    private T subject;

    public void setSubject(T subject) {
        this.subject = subject;
    }

    public T getSubject() {
        return subject;
    }
}

class EmployeeRequest extends Request<Employee> {
    // ...
}

class ConsultantRequest extends Request<Consultant> {
    // ...
}
```

You could similarly make the setSubject method abstract as you've described in your post, and then have separate implementations of it in your subclasses. Or you may not even need to subclass the Request class:

```
Request<Employee> employeeRequest = new Request<>();
employeeRequest.setSubject(/* ... */);
// ...
int employeeId = employeeRequest.getSubject().getEmployeeId();
```